# ACLs not applied on device by udev on user login

Tags: arch-linux, usb, udev, sane, loginctl

so there is a usb scanner:

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 055f:021e Mustek Systems, Inc. BearPaw 1200 TA/CS`

and a logged in user, registered in loginctl:

```
[mk@linux ~]$ loginctl session-status
1 - mk (1000)
           Since: Sat 2020-10-24 09:57:45 CEST; 8s ago
          Leader: 530 (lxdm-session)
            Seat: seat0; vc1
             TTY: tty1
         Service: lxdm; type x11; class user
           State: active
            Unit: session-1.scope
                  ├─530 /usr/lib/lxdm/lxdm-session
                  ├─539 xfce4-session
                  ├─625 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -s
                  ├─630 xfwm4
[...]
```

The scanner device file should have ACLs enabled for my user, so I can use the scanner:

```
getfacl  /dev/bus/usb/001/003
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/bus/usb/001/003
# owner: root
# group: scanner
user::rw-
user:mk:rw- <<<<<<<< HERE
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

It comes from the fact that udev runs following rules on this device (as I assume, don't know way to actually check that):

```
udevadm info --query=path --name=/dev/bus/usb/001/003
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-6

udevadm test  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-6
[...]
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/49-sane.rules
# Mustek BearPaw 1200 CS | Mustek BearPaw 1200 TA
ATTRS{idVendor}=="055f", ATTRS{idProduct}=="021e", MODE="0664", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
[...]
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
# SCSI and USB scanners
ENV{libsane_matched}=="yes", TAG+="uaccess"

Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
TAG=="uaccess", ENV{MAJOR}!="", RUN{builtin}+="uaccess"
[...]

DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-6
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/003
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
PRODUCT=55f/21e/100
[...]
ACTION=add
[...]
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=BearPaw 1200 TA/CS
[...]
run: '/bin/sh -c 'if test -e /sys//devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-6/power/control; then echo on > /sys//devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-6/power/control; elif test -e /sys//devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-6/power/level; then echo on > /sys//devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-6/power/level; fi''
run: 'uaccess' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE ACLs should be applied >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

The problem is that after the boot and login the permissions look like that:

```
getfacl  /dev/bus/usb/001/003
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/bus/usb/001/003
# owner: root
# group: scanner
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--
```

There is no user mk with write access and the scanner is not detected.

If I run:
`sudo udevadm trigger -c add /dev/bus/usb/001/003`

Then the permissions are set correctly:

```
getfacl  /dev/bus/usb/001/003
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/bus/usb/001/003
# owner: root
# group: scanner
user::rw-
user:mk:rw- << IT IS HERE AS IT'S SUPPOSED TO BE
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

The same happens if I physically replug the device.

The question is why it doesn't happen automatically on user login?

Answer (score 2):

Answering myself:
this is a bug in SANE rules, in line "ACTION!="add", GOTO="libsane_rules_end". I created bugreport and MR to them:
https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends/-/issues/371
https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends/-/merge_requests/541